# Is it possible to remove certain errors from Monaco Editor?

Tags: monaco-editor

I'm adding TypeScript support to my application [Data-Forge Notebook](http://www.data-forge-notebook.com/).

Its a notebook-style application for JavaScript. When I use the 'await' keyword in a code cell Monaco flags it as an error as shown in this screenshot:

[image: Error from Monaco Editor]

When the code is executed or exported this whole chunk of code gets wrapped in an `async` function so when that happens there is no error.

I need to be able to customize Monaco to remove this error because it doesn't make sense in this context.

Is it possible to remove or modify errors like this when using the Monaco editor?

Answer (score 5):

This is a bit late, but I've found another solution. It's possible to suppress errors by error code the following way:

```
monaco.languages.typescript.typescriptDefaults.setDiagnosticsOptions({
  diagnosticCodesToIgnore: [1375]
});
```

Where 1375 is the error code for the *"'await' expressions are only allowed at the top level of a file when that file is a module, but this file has no imports or exports. Consider adding an empty 'export {}' to make this file a module. (1375)"* error.

Comment: Better late than never! And I've just started open sourcing Data-Forge Notebook and revisiting the Monaco Editor integration, so thank you very much for this.

Comment: I'll make this the accepted answer once I get a change to try it out.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this problem myself by building a Monaco Editor package from code.

I started by forking Tim Kendrick's repo for packaging Monaco Editor: https://github.com/timkendrick/monaco-editor

I then cloned this using git's --recurse option so that I could also clone all the Monaco submodule repos.

I was then able to run Tim Kendrick's build process to package Monaco for use in my React app.

Finally I was able to remove the error message from Monaco's code and rebundle it for inclusion in my app.

It wasn't able to be configured in the way I hoped, but at least I was able to modify the code.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this; we've hit the same issue, and are hoping to avoid this path. If anything works, we'll be sure to share.

Answer (score 0):

I have a new answer to this question.

Tim Kendrick's package for Monaco Editor is based on Monaco code that is over a year old. So I was looking to build directly from the vscode repo.

Here's the commands for building Monaco Editor core direct from vscode:

```
git clone https://github.com/microsoft/vscode
cd vscode
yarn install
npm run compile
npx gulp editor-distro --max_old_space_size=2000
```

Note the use of **--max_old_space_size=2000** when running the Gulp build script. You need to do this to [increase Node.js memory](http://www.the-data-wrangler.com/nodejs-memory-limits/) so that it doesn't have a fatal out of memory error while building.

For a complete example: https://github.com/data-forge-notebook/monaco-build